# Refer to a row in another worksheet in an index formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 excel files - A and B.
In cell A1 of file B, I use an index formula to refer to a row in file A.
"INDEX('[A.xlsb]A'!$10:$10,1,2)" is the formula I use (referring row 10 in file A).

If I update the row number in another cell of file B, is it possible for this formula to refer to that cell to get the row number from file A?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 in this formula

=INDEX('[A.xlsb]A'!$10:$10,**1**,2)

defines the row relative to the range (as you only have one row, row 10, it can only be 1), so assuming you always want a row between 1 and 100 (adjust as required) you can use this version

=INDEX('[A.xlsb]A'!$1:$100,**C3**,2)

where C3 contains the row number you want

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to refer to another file is

```
'[FileNameAndExtension]SheetName'!Range
```

eg

```
=INDEX('[A.xlsb]Sheet1'!$10:$10,1,2)
```

Note, the other workbook must be open

Comment: Sheet name is the same as the file name. The formula in file B is INDEX('[A.xlsb]A'!$10:$10,1,2). Is it possible to modify this formula to update the row number (in file A) from a cell in file B?

Answer (score 0):

might want to try both Index and Match.  I solved a similar cross-workbook problem using them as per this link: https://exceljet.net/index-and-match